# JPA - DeletingMapping - ConstraingViolationException

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, backend

I'm new on Java. I'm doing a HTTPDeleting with JpaRepository(DeleteById) and i recived the following error: ConstraingViolationException - FK_QUESTION_ID cannot be null.

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Question {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "QUESTION_ID")
private int id;

@Column(nullable = false)
private String title;

@Column(nullable = false)
private String description;

// QUESTION_ID => FOREING KEY COLUMN
@OneToMany(orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "FK_QUESTION_ID")
private List<Answer> answers;

@Column(name = "LIKE_COUNT")
private int likeCount;

@Column(name = "INTEREST_AREA_ID", nullable = false)
private int interestAreaId;

@Column(name = "USER_ID", nullable = false)    
private int userId;

@Column
private boolean active;

@Column(name = "CREATED_DT", nullable = false)
private Date createdDate;
}



@Entity
@Data
public class Answer {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "ANSWER_ID")
private int answerId;

@Column
private String description;

@Column(name = "LIKE_COUNT")
private int likeCount;    

@Column(name = "USER_ID", nullable = false)
private int userId;

@Column
private boolean active;

@Column(name = "CREATED_DT", nullable = false)
private Date createdDate;

@Column(name = "FK_QUESTION_ID")
private int questionId;
}
```

I read that use CascadeType.Delete is not a good practice, so i used orphanRemoval but even in this way doesn't worked.

```
 questionRepository.deleteById(id);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your setup is almost correct, except you need to change couple of things here and there. Two important things are:

- `mappedBy = "question"` in the parent entity (`Question`) targets `question` field of child entity (`Answer`)
- `@JoinColumn` should be placed in the child class, through which you specify the column name `FK_QUESTION_ID` in the `Answer` table.

Hope, it helps.

```java
@Entity
@Data
public class Question {
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "question", orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private List<Answer> answers;
}
```

```java
@Entity
@Data
public class Answer {
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "FK_QUESTION_ID", nullable = false)
  private Question question;

  // since you seem to use lombok, you can also use 
  // answer.getQuestion().getId() instead of this method
  public int getQuestionId() {
    return this.question.getId(); // question lazy fetching
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works. I just need to understand JPA annotations better.